# get error apt-get search virtualbox E: Invalid operation search

Tags: apt, package-management, search

I tried to run

```
apt-get search virtualbox
```

but got this error message:

```
E: Invalid operation search
```

What am I doing wrong, which is the correct command to search for package information?

Answer (score 10):

Depending on your version of Ubuntu, the command is either `apt-cache search` (all versions) or `apt search` (14.04 and above), but not `apt-get search`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to drop the `get` part:

`apt search <word>`

Comment: No sweat - recommend that you read the other answer, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `aptitude` instead of `apt`. To search in titles only:

```
aptitude search virtualbox
```

To search in descriptions:

```
aptitude search ~dvirtualbox
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try and install 'virtualbox' via from the command line, it will say there's no installation candidate. When installing via apt, use 'virtualbox-qt'